# Selectively stopping the push notification listener or toggling the _displayInForeground for Expo Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

[Expo Push Notification](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/guides/push-notifications/) has the `_displayInForeground` property that can be set to allow receiving push notifications when the app in the foreground. Currently, I have the notification listener activated upon mounting the home screen, which is the very first screen.

Is there a way to either turn off the listener or toggle the `_displayInForeground` only when the user is in the chat screen? I don't want the push notifications for the chat messages coming in while the user is on the chat screen.

Comment: wich code that you used?

Comment: No resolution yet. I've only come up with a hacky way of getting around it. I've set up a listener with React Navigation that listens to the user arriving on the screen and sends a parameter to the backend that bypasses push notifications